# Handle ResourceNotFoundException in Silex

Tags: symfony, silex

I am trying to refactor an older codebase to use Silex - my thinking was that I could have Silex handle all actions it understands - and defer everything it doesn't to the legacy controller architecture:

```
$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

// TODO: Refactor old actions into Silex incrementally 
//$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {
//    return 'Hello ' . $app->escape($name);
//});

// NOTE: Defer handling to legacy controllers:actions
$app->error(function (\Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException $e, $code) {
    echo 'Silex not provided URL - default to legacy';
    try {

        $response = new Spectra_Application_Environment_Http_Response();
        $request = new Spectra_Application_Environment_Http_Request();

        $router = new Spectra_Application_Controller_Router_Adapter(
          $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], $request, new Common_Controller_Router($GLOBALS['AQUARIUS']['ROUTES'], key($GLOBALS['AQUARIUS']['ROUTES']))
        );

        $front = Spectra_Application_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->setResponseObject($response)->setRequestObject($request);

        $front->addPrePluginFilter(new Common_Controller_Filter_ActionCheck());

        echo cadorath_main($router, $front)->sendResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $result['success'] = false;
        $result['errors']['reason'] = $e->getMessage();

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
});

$app->run();
```

This isn't working. What am I not understanding of how Silex exception handling works?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this, but before I give you an answer I feel I have to point out a few things and this is too long for the comment field. Please take them as a friendly advice and not as a criticism.

First, Silex is being discontinued very soon. Since you are just starting out with migrating the codebase I suggest either a different microkernel-framework like SlimPHP or Lumen or switching to Symfony 4 using Flex. The latter is probably closest to the experience you get with Silex as it uses the same components it just gives you an easier path to extend your application with features from Symfony without having to manually wire everything up using Silex' provider logic.

The second point I want to make is your use of `echo`: It might be in there for debugging purposes, but if not, please be aware that this "breaks" most frameworks as they usually have some event system that is triggered during the runtime and just printing out stuff bypasses and in some cases even breaks those. When you are using Silex/Symfony you should use the Request and Response objects to handle the incoming and outgoing data and use return if you want to pass them on. So in your case instead of doing

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

You could do:

```
return new JsonResponse($result);
```

When you use the JsonResponse object it will set the headers for you and also do the JSON-encoding. So it's even easier and shorter than before.

As to your actual question, please provide more information on the errors you get. Maybe check your application or server logs (apache, nginx, ...).

My initial assumption is that the Request you are using for your legacy application does not contain all the necessary information. You might have to transfer over some data from Symfony's Request object or "fix" some of the values as they point to your new application, not the legacy application (e.g. SCRIPT_PATH) which might mess up some assumptions in your old code. Generally speaking try to identify which parts of the legacy code base use globals and check if those values are correctly set or refactor your application to not require those globals but instead read them from a config file for example.

Comment: I had no idea Silex was being discontinued - thanks for the heads up. We already use Symfony in other projects but for this 10 year old legacy MVC framework - starting with a micro-framework just made the transition easier. Eventually the backend will be re-done in Symfony. Baby steps. First the controllers, then DAL to entities, and lastly the UI (currently using ExtJS 3.2).

Comment: Take a look at Symfony 4 with Flex then. It builds a Symfony app, but containing only a minimal set of features by default, e.g. no forms, twig, doctrine, etc., and then you pull in features as needed. This is basically what you get from Silex, but it looks and feels like a classical Symfony application. This is the reason why Silex will be discontinued if no one takes it over, Flex provides the features within Symfony. You can just create an app from the skeleton, create a controller that listens to `/{path}` with `path: '.*'` as default and then try get your approach from above working.

Comment: You can also take a look at these slides from last year's SymfonyCon: https://slidr.io/derrabus/modernizing-with-symfony#1 The talk outlines how you can build a hybrid application (Symfony with legacy code as fallback) it might help you get this to work. Especially slide 21 showing how to wrap old apps in a controller action seems like it could be a good start.

Comment: I was planning on firing up S4 today on a personal project so the timing couldn't be better.